# How to specify a library to compile with python distutils

Tags: python, c, distutils

I am trying to create a c extension for python on my Raspberry Pi.
My setup.py looks like the following.
My c program uses the wiringPi library.
How do I instruct the setup program to use this library?
Without it, I get the following error.

> "ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dist_funct.so: undefined symbol: digitalWrite"

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='dist_funct', version='1.0',
ext_modules=[Extension('dist_funct', ['dist_funct.c'])])
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly list `libraries`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
    name='dist_funct',
    version='1.0',
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            'dist_funct',
            ['dist_funct.c'],
            libraries=["wiringPi"],
        ),
    ]
)
```

`Extension` has a lot of parameters, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension).

Comment: I have been reading the docs, but I'm not sure that I understand them.
I still get an error using your setup.
File "dist_c_call.py", line 2, in <module>
import dist_funct

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dist_funct.so: undefined symbol: digitalWrite

Comment: I don't know why, but running the install twice made it work!
I think I am OK for the moment. Thanks.